# NTFS disk has x % occupied but no files shown, doubled drive in disk management

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, ntfs

I had an external storage with NTFS format that on a linux machine and on a windows 10 machine was showing the files but not on a windows 7 machine. From my xp computer the NTFS disk has x % occupied but no files were shown.

I have checked/unchecked all the options to show hidden files, system protected files as that worked out for some and they found their files in some system generated hidden folder. Was hinted to use WinDirStat to get the hidden files but that didn't work neither (see the screenshot in the answer). Changed the drive letter as suggested, no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saw that in the device manager my external storage drive appears two times, once with an NTFS partition and once as a raw partition (see the screenshot). Tried to check the device with the builtin check disk utility but as I clicked to test it the window gone away as if it had done its job. From command line I tried it by `chkdsk X:` and it yielded:
    chkdsk can not be run on the drive
    The type of the file system is RAW.
    CHKDSK is not available for RAW drives

So now I did know that it has something wrong with its partition table and using the tool `Testdisk` I was able to solve the problem by rewriting the MBR sector of each of the two storage drives with "Intel" and after a reboot the files were accessible again.

- run testdisk
- select the desired drive like /dev/sda1 minding its size
- select the partition table type: Intel
- select [MBR Code] Write TestDisk MBR code to first sector
- repeat it for the duplicate drive with same size

[image]

The most comprehensive guide on this matter that I've found is: http://html5.litten.com/updated-how-to-fix-external-disk-drive-suddenly-became-raw/

Comment: While the link answers the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The answer to the question is: using the tool Testdisk I was able to rewrite the MBR sector of each of the two storage drives with "Intel" and after a reboot the files were accessible again.
This actually wasn't included in the reference that I have linked.

Comment: You said that you used Testdisk but your answer does not give any hint on how to use it. Although I personally use Testdisk all the time, other readers coming here might not be used to it. Instead of just linking a guide that you followed you should consider explaining what you did.

Comment: ok, added step by step instructions.